# Can I make Apex Legends run on DirectX 10?

Tags: apex-legends, directx-10

I have a bad computer but I want to play Apex. I tried putting "-dxlevel 10" in the launch properties box, but it didn't start. It's a Source Engine game, so shouldn't it use the same Source commands? Is there a way to make this work or is it a lost cause?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried running Directx11 games on my Directx10 PC. I had the GPU - Zotac Geforce 210.
To run Directx11 games on directx10 gpus you need to emulate Directx11 using dxcpl.

I have used it to run The Walking dead season 3. But it lagged like hell(given that i had 2 gb ram). 
dxcpl is unsuccesful in running Unreal Engine games.

Here is a link to dxcpl - [dxcpl](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zNeY66z8zU7f2LlpudK5K4IQu0mMfiij)

Here is a tutorial on how to use it - [Video](https://youtu.be/uGlbLThwraQ)

Comment: The question is whether it would work for Apex Legends?

Comment: I would suggest you link to the [DirectX SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10368). The path to dxcpl.exe is mentioned on the page.